# Match a lot of patterns in Haskell efficiently

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, packet

I have thought of using Haskell for a game server but when coding, I found myself looking at the part where I parse packets thinking "wow, this will result in a lot of pattern matching". This seeing the amount of matches to be done are many (walk there, attack that, loot that, open that, and so on).

What I do is:

1. Receive a packet
2. Parse the packet header into a hexadecimal String (say "02B5" for example)
3. Get rest of data from the packet
4. Match header in parseIO
5. Call the appropriate function with the packet content

It would be easy to map String -> method, but the methods have different amount of in-parameters.

I thought of the simple two ways of pattern matching shown below.

```
#1
packetIO :: String -> IO ()
packetIO packet =
  case packet of
    "02B5" -> function1
    "ADD5" -> function2
    ... and so on

#2
packetIO :: String -> IO ()
packetIO "02B5" = function1
packetIO "ADD5" = function2
... and so on
```

Both looking at performance and coding style, is there a way to better handle the packets received from the client?

If you have any resources or links I failed to find, please do point me in their direction!

**EDIT 130521**:

Seems like both alternatives, listed below, are good choices. Just waiting to see answers to my questions in the comments before choosing which was the best solution for me.

1. Storing (ByteString -> Function) in a Map structure. O(log n)
2. Converting ByteString to Word16 and pattern match. O(log n) through tree or O(1) through lookup tables

**EDIT 130521**:

Decided to go for pattern matching with Word16 as Philip JF said.
Both are great alternatives and while my guess is both is equally fast, Map might be faster seeing I don't have to convert to Word16, the other option gave more readable code for my use:

```
packetIO 0x02B5 = function1
packetIO 0xADD5 = function2
etc
```

Comment: Sounds more like a job for a `Map` (from `Data.Map`, from [`containers`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers)), with `ByteString` (I really don't like `String` ;)) as key type and **the handler function's type as value type**. If you have small packets of fixed length, then a type from `Data.Word` (like `Word16`) would suffice as a key. In that case, you might even want to use `Data.IntMap` for even better performance.

Comment: @Rhymoid: Could you please turn that into an answer, so that I can upvote it?

Comment: @Rhymoid: The received data is indeed ByteString at start. But wouldn't map give me a O(log n) time complexity when choices with lookup tables deliver O(1)? And how would the keys of ByteString be represented? Using 'pack' with all variants at load?

Comment: You're not getting a lookup table unless you use a suitable array index type (`Word16`, `Int`, a finite type), and you're not getting a jump table unless the lookup table is dense enough. At least, that's what I think an optimizer would do. A map gives you insertion and lookup with only `O(log n)` comparisons between `ByteString`s, but there are no real guarantees about the complexity of pattern matching on `String`s.

Comment: @Rhymoid: So say I use Word16, as mentioned by Philip JF, and only call other methods: `packetIO 0x02B5 -> function1`, with indexes from 0x0000 to 0xFFFF, that would be 0 to 65535. The table would not be dense enough for a jump table? Does GHC not fall back on a tree structure when it's not dense enough resulting in the same (log n) as a Map? Then it would be worth for readability.

Comment: You'd have to check, but I **think** GHC wouldn't make a jump table if you're just pattern matching on ten (plus `otherwise`) out of 2^16 cases. I think there's a threshold somewhere for the number (and density) of `Int`-like matches where GHC decides that it's better to have a jump table. Again: I'm not intimate enough with GHC's internals to know whether/when it decides to do that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why not parse to *numbers* (`Word16` in `Data.Word`?) and then do the matching with that, instead of using strings?  Haskell supports hex literals...

Comment: For parsing the result into Word16, I'm guessing this would be the way to do it?
`do let packet = unpack $ ByteString.take 2 received`
`let word = fromIntegral (packet!!1) * 0x100 + fromIntegral (packet!!0) :: Word16`
Then matching with: `packetIO 0x02B5 -> function1`

Comment: Pretty much. You could also try to use `cereal` or `binary`, which would be especially beneficial if the structure gets more complicated than reading command numbers.

Answer (score 10):

Both of your functions are equivalent.  The compiler desugars the second one to the first one.  Pattern matching is syntactic sugar for `case`.

`case` is optimal for this kind of thing.  It compiles to a jump table, which is O(1).  That means both of the solutions you listed are optimal.

As far as coding style goes, both styles are perfectly idiomatic.  I personally prefer `case` over pattern matching, but I know a lot of other people prefer pattern matching for top-level functions.

Comment: Does it compile to a jump table with `String`s too? I doubt it.

Comment: @Rhymoid Oops, I completely missed that.  Then I have no idea what `ghc` does in that case.